# Complete Riemannian metric on ${\mathbb R}^2\setminus\{0\}$.

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

It seems to me that the Riemannian metric $g_{ij}=\delta_{ij}/|x|^2$ on the punctured plane is complete, but I don't find a proof not involving explicit computations of the geodesic equation. Does anyone know one?

Comment: Shoud your title reflect $\mathbb{R}^{2}$?

Comment: it is isometric to the (infinite) cylinder: $(dr^2+r^2d\phi^2)/r^2=(dr/r)^2+d\phi^2=dz^2+d\phi^2$, where $z=\log r$

Comment: Although the Punctured $\mathbb{R}^2$ is not complete, applying the Riemannian metric $\frac{1}{r^2}(dx^2+dy^2)$, it becomes an infinite cylinder which is complete. Is it enough to prove that this is isomorphic to the metric in the question?

Comment: @GeorgeSimpson yes, how can you write down the isometry? it is not obvious to me.. also the infinite cyclinder is $\mathbb{R}\times S^1$ or what?

Answer (score 1):

As user8268 noted, this space is isometric to $\mathbb{R}\times S^1$. Using the polar coordinates $(r,\phi)$ on $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus \{0\}$, the isometry is 
$$F(r,\phi) = (\log r,\phi)\in \mathbb{R}\times S^1$$

Indeed, this map is  smooth and a bijection. So to check that it's an isometry it remains to consider the action on tangent vectors. Conveniently, the space $(\mathbb{R}^2\setminus \{0\},g_{ij})$ has two vector fields that form an orthonormal basis of every tangent plane:
$$
r\,\frac{\partial}{\partial r} \quad\text{and}\quad \frac{\partial}{\partial\phi}
$$
The map $F$ pushes them forward to $$
 \frac{\partial}{\partial z} \quad\text{and}\quad \frac{\partial}{\partial\phi}
$$
which are orthonormal vector fields on $\mathbb{R}\times S^1$. The push-forward is basically the chain rule: since $r=e^{z}$, 
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} = \frac{\partial r}{\partial z} \frac{\partial f}{\partial r} = e^z \frac{\partial f}{\partial r} = r\,\frac{\partial f}{\partial r} 
$$

Since $dF$ maps one orthonormal basis to another, it is an isometry.